# Txt file not opening

Tags: c#

**Hello, my Visual C# is running but when I enter a person's name in Form1.cs[Design] it won't open the file. My code is below and I'll also attach how I saved my txt and what errors are showing. I been trying to figure this out for hours. My goal is to learn how to save txt in my directory folder and how to call it in the .cs code.

````
`` ```
````

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbHvS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT1Ze.png)

Comment: Could you try to add this line before opening the file? _MessageBox.Show(Environment.CurrentDirectory);_ What is the currendirectory displayed in the MessageBox?

Comment: Hey Steve, it shows    D:\visual c#\pp22\bin\Debug

Answer (score 3):

> tldr;
>   
>   Your filename is **'BoysNames.txt.txt'**.

From the image it is clear that the exception occured, because there is no file called 'BoysNames.txt' in the current directory. I see what the problem is. You have hidden the extension of files and still the text file is displayed with its extension. (Note that since the 'exe' file doesn't show its extension but 'txt' is showing. It means it has double extensions). So, you need to do this:

```
boysFile = File.OpenText('D:\\visual c#\\pp22\\bin\\Debug\\BoysNames.txt.txt');
```

To avoid this type of problems in the future, try these steps.

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Click on File Explorer Options -> View
3. Uncheck this Option 'Hide extensiobns for known file types'

[image: Show ext]

Comment: We have an image that shows the files are in the _supposed_ current directory. The code should work if the current directory is the one where VS runs its executables in a debug session.

Comment: You're right. DIrectory is correct but the text file has double extensions since the 'known extensions' are hidden but still it is showing .txt at the end.

Comment: It still won't open up. This is where the file is located: D:\visual c#\pp22\bin\Debug    How can I call that in my code?

Comment: Did you try showing the extensions of known file types? Please perform that step and you will see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like it will not open the file because it is not where you are saying it is. Look in the error, it tells you where it is looking for the file, is it really there?

Comment: That is where I'm having trouble, trying to figure out how to call it or if I even saved it correctly.